# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que el efecto Parallax sea responsivo?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo un problema al hacer un efecto `parrallax`, cuando lo tengo en dispositivos laptop o computadora no hay problema el efecto continúa, el problema surge cuando ya cambia a dispositivos mas pequeños (teléfono, tablet) el efecto ya no se presenta.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

He intentado hacerlo desde el CSS, para los diferentes dispositivos, sin embargo no funciona.

```
/*------------- FUNCION PARA REALIZAR EL PARALLAX --------------------------*/

let parallax = document.querySelector('.parallax2');

let titulo = document.querySelector('.titulo');

function scrollParallax(){
    let scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    parallax.style.transform = 'translateY(' + scrollTop * -0.3 + 'px)';//scroll de la imagen
    titulo.style.transform = 'translateY(' + scrollTop * -0.1 + 'px)'; //scroll del titulo
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollParallax); //cuando hace scroll se ejecuta la fn



.contenedor{
position: relative;
height: 250px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.parallax2{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
background-image: url("../../images/telemedicina/Tecnologiasanitaria.jpg");
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 100vh;
margin: 20px 0;
z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: El problema estaría en CSS, en la clase padre de `parallax2` y éste mismo. Debes agregar todo tu estilo CSS y también @media queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faltaría trabajar un poco más con algunas medidas y, muy bien con @media Queries, sobre los estilos responsivos.

Yo realice un ejemplo básico tomando una medida máximo de `500px`.

Lo básico ya está, pero tú agregas tus propios estilos y diseños para las demás @media.

```js
let parallax = document.querySelector('.parallax2'); 
let titulo = document.querySelector('.titulo'); 

function scrollParallax() { 
   
   let scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop; 
   parallax.style.transform = 'translateY(' + scrollTop * -0.3 + 'px)'; 
   titulo.style.transform = 'translateY(' + scrollTop * -0.1 + 'px)';  

} 

window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollParallax);
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box
}


body {
 min-height: 3000px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.contenedor { 
 position: relative; 
 width: 100%;
 height: 250px;
 overflow: hidden; 
} 

.parallax2 { 
 position: absolute; 
 width: 100%; 
 background-image: url("https://placeimg.com/1000/480/people"); 
 background-size: cover; 
 background-position: center; 
 background-repeat: no-repeat; 
 height: 100vh; 
 margin: 20px 0; 
 z-index: -1; 
}


@media (max-width: 500px) {
 
 .contenedor {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
 }
 
 .parallax2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
 
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="contenedor">
   <div class="parallax2"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Al parecer aquí en el Snippet no funciona bien bien el JS. Pero en mi local si funciona bien.

Comment: Si te ayudo ésta respuesta, no olvides marcar con el  check ✓ para que sirva también a otros que quieran el mismo resultado...